# maven compile fails because i have a non-maven jar

Tags: maven

I have a couple of internal libraries which I haven't/don't know how to add to my local maven repository. I've added them to the project's classpath but my maven-compile fails stating that it can't find the classes in the external jars (as expected):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project proj: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
dir\src\main\java\package\MyClass.java:[8,25] package blah does not exist

dir\src\main\java\package\MyClass.java:[9,25] package blah does not exist

dir\src\main\java\package\MyClass.java:[21,12] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Blah
location: class package.MyClass

dir\src\main\java\package\MyClass.java:[28,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Blah
location: class package.MyClass
```

How do I tell maven about a jar I've sneakily added to my project's classpath so it can use it to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure you can access the system classpath without a lot of hackary. You can do one of two other things: a system scope dependency or add it to your local repo.

To use a [system dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies), just add an entry for each jar you wish to add. Give them the scope "system" and add a `<systemPath>` to each. Something like this.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

You could then use -D jvm properties if you insist on changing the location and compile time.

Adding them to the [local repo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) is a bit of a pain, but the more long term solution.

Comment: thanks that works fine. the jar exists within the project so i just use `${basedir}/.../jar.jar`

Comment: +1 on "Adding them to the local repo is a bit of a pain, but the more long term solution" part of the answer.  System dependencies are a drain on the portability of a project.  You will be much better off maintaining that dependency like you do any other (and deploying it to a published maven repo at some point).