# Recommendable Maven repository search engines?

Tags: java, maven-2, repository, search-engine

[mavensearch.net](http://mavensearch.net) doesn't know current versions in many cases, [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) is a bit more up to date but doesn't show repositories from where a package can be downloaded, what I would find very useful.

What Maven respository search engines do you use and like?

Comment: mvnrepository.com is terrible, none of the things I have looked up are updated correctly

Comment: mvnrepository.com is blocked by both chrome and firefox as a malware site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest using the official one, http://search.maven.org/ . The indices for Maven Central are updated hourly as new artifacts are added to the Central Repository.

Answer (score 14):

There is no perfect one, use several of them.

- http://mvnrepository.com/

Some Nexus repositories:

- http://repository.apache.org/
- https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/
- http://repository.sonatype.org/
- https://oss.sonatype.org/

Down or no longer available:

- http://www.jarvana.com/
- http://www.artifact-repository.org/
- http://maven.ozacc.com/
- http://www.mavenreposearch.com/

I use most of time http://www.jarvana.com/ or http://mavensearch.net/ and the above Nexus repositories.

Comment: http://www.mvnbrowser.com does show which repository or repositories contain a given dependency. (not sure about any of the others)

Comment: @Chris http://www.mvnbrowser.com/ indices are totally out of date making it [useless as search engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377020/managing-maven-dependancies-new-versions-and-non-repo-libraries/3377257#3377257).

Comment: Update : Jarvana is now definitively down.
http://jarvana.blogspot.fr/2013/08/goodbye-jarvana.html

Comment: I have found http://maven.eea.sk/artifactory/webapp/home.html?3 that allows you to search using checksum.