# How to convert a java/weblogic/ANT application into a spring boot/maven application?

Tags: spring-boot

We have a a java/jsp servlet application running on weblogic today.
I would like to convert this application to a spring-boot application?
The app uses ANT for build and i would like to also figure out all jar dependecies and convert this app to a maven application.

I also have standalone java applications running on commandline triggered by a cron job that i would like to do the same .

Please advise on how I ca do this.

Sri

Comment: can i build a spring-boot starter project just to generate sample files?

Comment: Sounds like a large effort. My advice is to start small and build incrementally. In regard to figuring out "all jar dependencies", search for the coordinates of each on a remote maven repo (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430423/recommendable-maven-repository-search-engines).

Comment: since it a jsp/servlet project what spring-boot starter project will help?

Comment: Depends on what your app does. But consider searching the Spring Boot samples (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples).

Comment: Curious to know if you were able to convert the project? Any links / tips that you have used?